# Permutation or combination data python

Tags: python, django-views

I get from my database somes dates and turn them in dictionaries, for example:

```
{1: [<Variable: Low>, <Variable: Medium>, <Variable: High>]}
{2: [<Variable: Low>, <Variable: Medium>, <Variable: High]}
{3: [<Variable: Low>, <Variable: Medium>, <Variable: High]}
```

In my problem, i need interpolate this variables and as a final result, I want to:

```
{1:High,2:High,3:High},{1:High,2:High,3:Medium}{1:High,2:High,3:Low}
{1:High,2:Medium,3:High},{1:High,2:Medium,3:Medium},{1:High,2:Medium,3:Low},
{1:High,2:Low,3:High},{1:High,2:Low,3:Medium},{1:High,2:Low,3:Low},
{1:Medium,2:High,3:High},{1:Medium,2:High,3:Medium}{1:Medium,2:High,3:Low}
{1:Medium,2:Medium,3:High},{1:Medium,2:Medium,3:Medium},{1:Medium,2:Medium,3:Low},
{1:Medium,2:Low,3:High},{1:Medium,2:Low,3:Medium},{1:Medium,2:Low,3:Low},
{1:Low,2:High,3:High},{1:Low,2:High,3:Medium}{1:Low,2:High,3:Low}
{1:Low,2:Medium,3:High},{1:Low,2:Medium,3:Medium},{1:Low,2:Medium,3:Low},
{1:Low,2:Low,3:High},{1:Low,2:Low,3:Medium},{1:Low,2:Low,3:Low}
```

Anybody have some idea how to do this?

Note I: both the number of dictionaries and the number of Variable may be different.

Note II: The code is out of the norm, this is just the idea.

Comment: This is combination, not interpolation.  Use the **itertools** package.

Comment: Other than that, I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do.  Your posted code is not legal Python.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably gonna need to use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module.
I don't know if this is what you need, but I think it can help you get there:

```
for r in itertools.product(['high', 'med', 'low'], repeat = 3):
  print r

('high', 'high', 'high')
('high', 'high', 'med')
('high', 'high', 'low')
('high', 'med', 'high')
('high', 'med', 'med')
('high', 'med', 'low')
('high', 'low', 'high')
('high', 'low', 'med')
('high', 'low', 'low')
('med', 'high', 'high')
('med', 'high', 'med')
('med', 'high', 'low')
('med', 'med', 'high')
('med', 'med', 'med')
('med', 'med', 'low')
('med', 'low', 'high')
('med', 'low', 'med')
('med', 'low', 'low')
('low', 'high', 'high')
('low', 'high', 'med')
('low', 'high', 'low')
('low', 'med', 'high')
('low', 'med', 'med')
('low', 'med', 'low')
('low', 'low', 'high')
('low', 'low', 'med')
('low', 'low', 'low')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks teteu =]

Comment: Yay, glad I could help! :)